# Render handlebars.php duplicate some content

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js, mustache.php

I have a question for you and please help me. I use this library in my project : https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php.
Now from my route I make the render of template. In template I have

```
<div class="winners col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
{{#data}}
    <div class="lineWinners">
        <h2><img src="{{ sImgWinners }}" alt=""><span>Liste:</span></h2>
        {{#each aWinners}}
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 details">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img src="{{{ sImageUrl }}}" alt="{{ this.sGift }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                    <p><strong>{{ this.sWinner }}</strong><br />{{ this.sGift }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/data}}
```

The problem is that In the browser I get 3 times :

```
Liste:
Liste:
Liste:
```

and one `{#each} {/each}`, this is correct. So the idea is that content who is outside of each is duplicate 3 times. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english
I have a method

```
public function renderHandlebars($template,$data)
{
    $o_handlebars = new Handlebars();

    $o_template = $o_handlebars->loadTemplate($template);

    return $o_template->render($template, $data);
}
```

Comment: How do you call render-function?

Comment: can you show more code OR something live example

Comment: I edited the question : @leguana

Comment: What's the `data` helper?